# Clear var defined in UserControl from main Form

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, user-controls

I've a UserControl where I define some vars and also has some components like buttons, textbox and some others:

```
private List<string> bd = new List<string>();
private List<string> bl = new List<string>();
```

It's possible to access to those vars from `namespace WindowsFormsApplication1`? How? If I try to do this from `private void recuperarOriginalesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` I got a error:

```
bl = new List<string>();
blYear.Enabled = true;
btnCargarExcel.Enabled = true;
filePath.Text = "";
nrosProcesados.Text = "";
executiontime.Text = "";
listBox1.DataSource = null;
```

What's the right way to do this?

**EDIT: clarify**
What I'm looking for is to clean values each time I access a menu item. For textBox and others components it works thanks to the suggestions made here but for List I don't know how to set it to null

Comment: What error do you get? And what exactly are you trying to do? Does that method belong to the same class that holds those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always access any variable that you define, any control that you place on your `UserControl` at all those places, where you have placed your UserControl.

Just make sure, you have made your variables `public` and exposed your Controls through `public properties` i.e

suppose you have kept a `TextBox`  on your UserControl for Names. In order to use it outside, you must expose it through a `public property`

```
public partial class myUserControl:UserControl
{
   public TextBox TxtName{ get{ return txtBox1;}}

   public ListBox CustomListBoxName
   {
      get
      {
         return ListBox1;
      }
      set
      {
         ListBox1 = value;
      }
   }

   public List<object> DataSource {get;set;}

}
```

and you can use it on the form you have dragged this usercontrol i.e.

```
public partial form1: System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
   public form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       MessageBox.Show(myUserControl1.TxtName.Text);

       MessageBox.Show(myUserControl1.CustomListBoxName.Items.Count);
       myUserControl1.DataSource = null;   
   }
}
```

similary you can expose your variables, through public properties. That way you can also control whether you want some of your variables to be readonly or what!

Comment: fine, I learn something new but in my case I want to expose 25 controls, is that the only way I can do this? I need to create a `public` method for each control in order to expose them to Form1?

Comment: exactly. that's the only way. otherwise, you will have to findControl in your UC at the place where you have used it. And its very ugly. Declaring public variables are the neatest way

Comment: good, can you please add some code to your post for `List<t>` and for `DataSource`? What's `TxtName`? The Name of the Control?

Comment: TxtName is the name of public property that I exposed in the UserControl. see the `myUserControl` definition

Comment: I wrote this `public TextBox textBox1
        {
            get {
                return textBox1;
            }
        }` but gets this error "Error 1 The type 'CMApp.RecoverExcelUC' already contains a definition for 'textBox1' d:\Work\ClanMovil\CMApp\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\RecoverExcelUC.Designer.cs 141 46 CMApp
"

Comment: give it some other name. textBox1 is already the name of the original control in the same scope

Comment: Ok, what about the sample for Lists and ListBox elements?

Comment: you can expose them in the same way as you exposed a textBox. wait i should update my code

Comment: before update your code take a look at the edit I made seconds ago, I explain what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose a property and then access that property on the usercontrol-instance from your main form:

**UserControl**

```
public List<string> BD {get; set;}
```

**Main form**

```
MyUserControl.BD = new List<string>();
```